# Check how many times a letter in the alphabet was used as a starting letter for a key in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, function

Create a function that returns an array of object that contains the following:
{letter: 'A', count: 15} -- the *letter* will be in alphabetical order and the *count* is count of the countries that starts with letter 'A'.

```
    const countries = [
  {
    name: 'Afghanistan',
    capital: 'Kabul',
    languages: ['Pashto', 'Uzbek', 'Turkmen'],
    population: 27657145,
    flag: 'https://restcountries.eu/data/afg.svg',
    currency: 'Afghan afghani'
  },
  {
    name: 'Åland Islands',
    capital: 'Mariehamn',
    languages: ['Swedish'],
    population: 28875,
    flag: 'https://restcountries.eu/data/ala.svg',
    currency: 'Euro'
  },
  {
    name: 'Albania',
    capital: 'Tirana',
    languages: ['Albanian'],
    population: 2886026,
    flag: 'https://restcountries.eu/data/alb.svg',
    currency: 'Albanian lek'
  } //...this country array reaches up to a country that starts with 'Z'
];
```

Here's my solution so far:

```
function alphaCountry() {
    const alphaChar = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVEWXYZ'
    const finalObj = [];
    let alphaIndexer = 0;

    while (alphaIndexer !== alphaChar.length) {
    const startsWith = countries.filter((obj) => obj.name.startsWith(alphaChar[alphaIndexer]))
    finalObj.push({'letter': alphaChar[alphaIndexer], 'count': startsWith.length + ' times'})
    alphaIndexer++
  }

  return finalObj;
}
```

It works. Is there a shorter way or better way to execute this? Thank you!

Comment: _"Is there a shorter..."_ - Define "shorter"? Lines of code? Function calls? ...? _"...or better way..."_ - Define "better"? Time complexity? Faster? ...?

Comment: you're iterating the whole countries array 26 times, once for each letter. You can rewrite the function to iterate only once and populate a hash table of counts. In terms of performance it won't matter much for such tiny input though.

Comment: @Kinglish I have already made a code that works. I'm just wondering if there would be a better way of executing this. Thank you.

Comment: @Charles - my bad I didn't see your attempt. I retract my comment

Comment: Algorithm, your solution is based upon, is pretty slow. Even for array of 195 records (number of countries in the world) it performs [5 times slower](https://jsben.ch/EFmA8), compared to something, [more appropriate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68259202/11299053).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `Array.prototype.reduce()` to calculate the number of occurrences of each letter as initial, then return the resulting key-value pairs sorted appropriately:

```js
const countries = [
  {name: 'Ukraine'},
  {name: 'Bulgaria'},
  {name: 'Cyprus'},
  {name: 'Andorra'},
  {name: 'United Kingdom'},
  {name: 'Canada'}
]


const getStartingLetters = arr => {
  const occurences = arr
    .reduce((acc, {name}) => {
      const startingLetter = name[0]
      acc[startingLetter] = ( acc[startingLetter] || 0 ) + 1
      return acc
    }, {})
  
  return Object
    .keys(occurences)
    .sort()
    .map(letter => ({letter, count: occurences[letter]}))
}


console.log(getStartingLetters(countries))
```

Comment: Thank you Sir! It's faster compared to my solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following code to fetch the number of occurences

```
const names= countries.reduce((v1,v2)=>{
    const startLetter = v2.name[0];
        v1[startLetter] = (v1[startLetter] || 0) + 1;
        return v1;  
        },{})
    
    console.log(names)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const countedLetters=countries.reduce((acc,country)=>{
    for(let i=0;i<country.name.length;i++)
    {
        if(country.name[i] in acc)
        {
            acc[country.name[i]]++
        }
        else
        {
            acc[country.name[i]]=1
        }
        return acc
    }  
},{})
console.log(countedLetters)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hello, please don't post code only and add an explantation as to why you think that this is the optimal solution. People are supposed to learn from your answer, which might not occur if they just copy paste code without knowing why it should be used.